# What is the difference between explicitly typing a generic function parameter and implicitly typing it in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Below is a very basic setup where I have a class `App` that handles HTTP requests (imagine it does, the code for the HTTP server is not shown below).

```
interface CallbackError {
  error: string;
}

type HandlerCallback = <T>(payload?: CallbackError | T) => void;

type Handler = (callback: HandlerCallback) => void;


// omitted code here is a server that calls handleRequest on a request
class App {
  public constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router = router;
  }

  private handleRequest = () => {
    this.router.handleRequest(this.sendResponse);
  };

  private sendResponse: HandlerCallback = (payload?: any) => {
    // do something
  };
}
```

When a request comes in, `handleRequest` is called on the `Router` class. A route in the `Router` is simply a callback that is called, nothing more, and this callback is of type `Handler`. `Handler` takes another callback as a parameter, of type `HandlerCallback`.

```
class Router {
  private routes: Handler[] = [];

  public addRoute = (callback: Handler) => {
    this.routes.push(callback)
  };

  // the request is handled by simply calling the callbacks added
  public handleRequest = (callback: HandlerCallback) => {
      this.routes.forEach(cb => cb(callback))
  };
}

interface User { id: number }

const handler1: Handler = (callback) => {
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    callback({ id: 1 })
  } else {
    callback({ error: "error" })
  }
}

const handler2: Handler = (callback: (payload: CallbackError | User) => void) => {
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    callback({ id: 1 })
  } else {
    callback({ error: "error" })
  }
}

const router = new Router();

router.addRoute(handler1)
router.addRoute(handler2)
```

As you can see above, I defined two "routes", ie two `Handler` callbacks to be called by the router, and they each take a callback parameter of type `HandlerCallback`. **My question relates to how to type the latter callbacks.** In `handler1`, I leave the parameter implicitly typed, so it is typed with the definition of `HandlerCallback` which is a generic type. In TS playground, if you hover over each occurrence of `callback` in `handler1`, you see different types.

If you do the same and hover over the two calls to `callback` in `handler2` they have the same type as was explicitly typed in the parameter.

**So my questions are**
- in `handler1`, why doesn't TS show the same type when you hover over the calls to `callback`? In particular, in `handler1`, `callback` is called with either parameter of type `User` or parameter of type `CallbackError`, so why isn't the type of `callback` inferred to be `CallbackError | User`?

Comment: I don't understand why `HandlerCallback` is generic in the first place; what specifically is the advantage of the code you have over just `type HandlerCallback = (payload?: unknown) => void;`?  It seems to me that either your code is unnecessarily generic, *or* you've got the type parameter in the wrong place (`type Foo<T> = (x: T)=>void` vs `type Bar = <T>(x: T)=>void`, the difference being who specifies the type parameter; the `T` in a `Foo<T>` is specified by the function *implementer*, where the `T` in `Bar` is specified by the function *caller*) and your types need to be fixed.

Comment: @jcalz using the version of `HandlerCallback` where the generic parameter is defined by the implementer is definitely an option, and I do understand the distinction between the two ways of writing the generic function. My question has more to do with understanding how inferred types work with generics. Here is a way to get an error that I don't comprehend: right now, `sendResponse`'s parameter is typed as `payload?: any`, but if you change that to `CallbackError | User` the error is that T is not assignable to User.

Comment: I think what I was hoping for is the following: a function of type `Handler` takes in a parameter `HandlerCallback`; when you actually define a variable that is of type `Handler`, you define all the places where the callback parameter (of type `HandlerCallback`) will be called. So, at this point, you know what the type of the callback should be. In the case of `handler1`, you know its function parameter needs to accept a parameter of type CallbackError | User. That is, the generic type is resolved because we've seen all the call sites.

Comment: Of course, `handler1`'s function parameter could accept a supertype of `CallbackError | User`, but that would make it a subtype of the type of the callback defined by the call sites in `handler1`.

Comment: `sendResponse()` can't restrict its inputs to `CallbackError | User` because it needs to accept all possible inputs.  That's what `<T>(payload?: CallbackError | T) => void;` means; it must accept a `payload` of type `T` for any `T` that the *caller* wants.  And so it's not functionally different from `(payload?: unknown) => void`.  Note that my `Foo<T>` and `Bar` examples are not two ways of writing the same thing; they are different (but related) types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your question at face value: in `handler1`, the `callback` parameter is given no explicit type annotation, and is thus inferred [contextually](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) from the annotated type of `handler1` as `Handler`.  A `Handler` is a function whose first argument is a `HandlerCallback`, and so `callback` is inferred to be `HandlerCallback`.

The type `HandlerCallback` is a generic function, so inside `handler1`, the `callback` parameter will be treated as such a generic function.   Each time you call it, its type parameter `T` will be specified... if you don't do it manually, it will be inferred from the arguments to the function.  Thus, you get this behavior:

```
callback({ id: 1 }) // hover
/* callback: <{ id: number; }>(
    payload?: CallbackError | { id: number;} | undefined
   ) => void */
```

and

```
callback({ error: "error" }) // hover
/* callback: <{ error: string; }>(
     payload?: CallbackError | { error: string;} | undefined
   ) => void */
```

and even

```
callback("hello") // hover
/* callback: <string>(payload?: string | CallbackError | undefined) => void */
```

That's just normal generic function behavior.

---

If you expected `callback` to be inferred inside the function based on what you actually call it with, contextual typing doesn't work that way.  Let's look at a different example with the same behavior, but with no generics:

```
interface Person {
    name: string,
    age: number
}
type PersonTaker = (person: Person) => void;

const personTaker1: PersonTaker = person => {
    // person inferred as Person, not {name: {toUpperCase(): string}}
    console.log("HELLO " + person.name.toUpperCase() + "!!");
}

const personTaker2: PersonTaker = (person: { name: { toUpperCase(): string } }) => {
    console.log("HELLO " + person.name.toUpperCase() + "!!");
}
```

Both `personTaker1` and `personTaker2` are annotated to be `PersonTaker` functions.  But `personTaker1` allows its `person` parameter to be inferred by the compiler, while `personTaker2` explicitly annotates its `person` parameter.  In `personTaker1`, the type of `person` is inferred as `Person`, contextually from the type `PersonTaker`.  It is *not* inferred as the narrower type `{ name: { toUpperCase(): string } }`, even though that's all the body of `personTaker1` uses, and is the explicitly annotated type of `person` in `personTaker2`.  This is just how contextual type inference of function parameters works in TypeScript.

---

Does that make it more clear?  If you understand why `person` is inferred as `Person` instead of as `{ name: { toUpperCase(): string } }` in `personTaker1`, but still have a problem with `callback` being inferred as `HandlerCallback` instead of as `(payload: CallbackError | User) => void` in `handler1`, then you might want to clarify your question a bit.  In particular, please be sure you understand the difference between a generic *type* referring to a non-generic function, like `type Foo<T> = (x: T)=>void`, and a non-generic type referring to a generic function, like `type Bar = <T>(x: T)=>void`.  Those are different types.  For example, a value of type `Bar` is assignable to a variable of type `Foo<string>`, but not vice versa.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJwDYYEaINYCiUUA9lMgN4BQyty0pUAXMgM5hSgDmA3FQL5UqYAJ4AHFAAk4IACYZo6LLgR5kAXmQAeACoA+ABRi4IjCTiyA-CyU58RRsgA+yHQEoNe5ADcSwWXwA9IG0RiZmFtbIAK4geCAkAO4gHupevv58wuJSMvLQGsgGCJh2qizScgpQtip4qel+AUJUwcgkALbAYJCyyAgksigAFtAowKzIcGzQ3gVgw3Bg-aWTi1UQAEoQAI7REOztIFPIULv77FQIGHCskwCCYmKUNHRi0dgYwAj9JCDsUGiCDAZCMnG8SxQpGikGYyE2JBh0A81DoaOQCwmADpobDCrjoHw0YJXrQxODIch1vltnsDstNAYGi90XRMawcYjYVjqQpaRcwAZ2VjWBA5NtWGI-qK3ES6PwsmjycAIZAZuKDlL-hAKnlqrV8IUwqZzFYWDIRMzUazkG1ZCQ2J0IJiQFxScgFQIhNdbpMEUjyNayRS1QTWLqNlAANoAXUKscVbw+Xx+Flk-rVjJKynwEfyUCt7rRwrDWPerGGxVKdTc7s97raCyh53pyAmVL1ED62BEbGAHTEGF72a+roxoxWOdUkzTXfd70+3w7G35raz1dzyEq+YNqkLNvH2NLMDIBEQlYQ2E8-WwVan9VrxL4JNAsPgSGQAFVRYG27IWCA0QdNgBQkgM-zLLy0AAIx5tURojjW17UO6iH4AYFB-iw0Eeh4bTDCQcxQA2ABUk5lHgLBaJh-gAUBIFQDwHqGEWbzhKaUS7oQxBkM4lBYcggHAYS-B8bEQwwKAc42syGR9CRgRCGiaGqBh9A8XCABEDBkJpuG2iEBFEaR5F1FRmE6XCALcEx-AsQeyDGCakQ2BuqgOLxLgWRpLDWa6PCiS44kQJJIDSayslNMgClKXQKl4AYmmjFgJCaXhhmEdAJnxVRflcIYTkRGabAcNwfFcR55BBXIIVSbIkX+NFinusAMBFAAsksww4nknRMsgXgAAxYgArCirG0PFam0cgOH8OlVKZcRB6BGROXaDR-6CfRhLMQYE3ooVHGufelV8ZtdHCYxgUxDVoXhQ5DXyYpxL0BgoosjaU3eYwLDaRpenzQZi3GSta1uZRG3qb9JWcP5e0HYd7EuWgENnV50NkL5pX+TdwX3bIiO0E9TV1qhEOJclZhpUIYHSpBnZQAATHBBTrveLDGkVJ0UejX4-k9+50K1HVdT1ch9R4Q2jeNB7fQJc2PvKb0fUG6Ly5Zf2WYDSu0IIdMQacXJs4JECJPCxtQEyWQElAWJphmEAGFBUDQbWtv27I6bG87jNMx4LSvtA74oAACtArB-J9tAgHAHQ6rD3AADTunAXAJ0JDFeqIEjIOHUCRyAOhwHgJtGBHfwsPnhdPVk4GHBIBd-MXpeu1XFdFyXJuN4XyENiEPdR6AMAMF2UyTNXfxJ4JJDLBQsfxywFAgp+TyKLcTtuNjcNcPwgjKdKJAKFiZhcIlkgEAAMpfADyyB6QA1I5HdYgvEBYiva81Bv-VP5pACE-80rPm9PTZ+TdO6txZnnDuLcy6DxAEvQSccE6YU-o3dAoomTbzKqJIGaRo6-H+Efd+p9z5X1vvfZAT8EGvxQR-Egq8ME-w8H-QBwCvQtC4S0IAA)

Answer (score 0):

> in handler1, callback is called with either parameter of type User or parameter of type CallbackError

Not accurate, `{ id: 1 }` has the same shape as a `User`, but nothing in code actually makes/asserts it to be the `User`

```
const foo = { id: 1 };
type Foo = typeof foo; // { id: number } not User
```

Comment: `User` and `{id: number}` are the same type precisely because they have the same shape. Note that `var a: { id: number }; var a: User;` compiles fine, and that wouldn't work if the compiler thought they were different types. I'm also not sure how this addresses the question asked; can you elaborate?

Comment: @jcalz the question is: _why doesn't TS show the same type when you hover over the calls to callback_

Comment: Inside the implementation of `handler1`, if you hover over the first `callback` call it says that `V` is inferred to be `{ id: number; }`, and if you hover over the second call it says that `V` is inferred to be `{ error: string; }`.  I assume the question is why those aren't the same type as each other.  My answer to that question is that `callback` is a generic function whose type parameter is specified by the *caller*, and different calls can have different type parameter specifications.  But the whole question seems like there is some confusion over generic types, so ‍♂️

Comment: @jcalz indeed you are right that hovering over each call site in `handler1` gives you the type inferred from simply that particular call site. However, both call sites refer to the same callback function, which needs to be able to be called in both places; so my doubt is, why doesn't TS show the type to be a union of the types inferred on all the call sites?